# Added opencv_world400.lib and opencv_world400d.lib to dependencies, still getting LNK2001 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I've added opencv_world400.lib and opencv_world400d.lib to the dependencies, but I'm still getting this error in MSVS2017:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenCLTest, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>OpenCLTest.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z)
1>c:\users\chubak\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\OpenCLTest\x64\Release\OpenCLTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "OpenCLTest.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

There were no other lib files in the folder, just those two. What causes this problem I don't know.

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:\\Users\\Chubak\\Pictures\\index.jpg");
    if (image.empty())
        return -1;
    imshow("TEST", image);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**3 steps:**

**1.** [C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qknKQ.png)

**2.** [Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3VKr.png)

**3.** [Linker -> General -> Additional Include Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SToP7.png)